# Predicting circle-circle bounce vector when aiming one at another

Tags: java, libgdx, trigonometry

I am making a game with libGDX (with box2d) in which you drag and aim one circle body at another then release to fire. I would like to be able to predict the path of the second circle based on the aim of the first. very like 8 ball pool when aiming your shot.

I have been playing around with various trig solutions but i just cant get it to work at all! I have also been reading about ray casting in which I would cast a ray from the center of the first circle body in the direction i am aiming. this would tell me where the ray intersects the second circle body (if it does so) but it would not be correct as the circle fixture would not actually collide where they ray does because it obviously has a radius.

Is the trig solution the correct path or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: For the ray method, treat the second circle's radius as if it is the sum of the radii of both circles. Then the collision point you calculate will actually be the center point of the first circle at the location of collision.

Comment: I can see how this would give an accurate indication of where the contact will take place but I thought a ray reports an intersection only when it 'hits' a body. So how would I make the ray treat the expanded radius as an intersection without actually expanding the body?

Comment: Ive just realised I could add another body or fixture to circle 2 and just mask out unwanted collisions. ill give it a try.